# ScrollController not working without a container

Tags: flutter

I have a ScrollController in my page to work with infinite scroll but when the list builder is not in a Container the ScrollController listeners does not work.

Works

```
Container(
  height: 400,
  child: Observer(
    builder: (_) {
      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: passeiosController.passeios.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) => PasseioCard(
          passeioModel: passeiosController.passeios[index],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

Not working

```
Observer(
  builder: (_) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      controller: _scrollController,
      itemCount: passeiosController.passeios.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => PasseioCard(
        passeioModel: passeiosController.passeios[index],
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborate as to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked. I had a list view builder inside a listview. Putting the controller in the parent listview worked correctly.